# Ransack not working (no error, just not functioning)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

Would love it if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong. Followed the docs: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

My model defines that a `Signup has_many Inventories`

Controller code:

```
def index
  @q = Inventory.search(params[:q])
  @inventories = @q.result.includes(:signup)
end
```

View code:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: url_for(controller: 'inventories', action: 'index') do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :item_name_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :item_name_cont %>
  <%= f.label :signup_email_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :signup_email_cont %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :item_name, "Item", default_order: :desc) %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, 'signups.email', "Email") %></th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th colspan="5"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% Inventory.all.each do |inventory| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= inventory.item_name %></td>
        <td><%= inventory.signup.email %> %></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, if it's helpful, if I remove the `url:` specification in the search form, I get an error: `No route matches [GET] "/inventories/search"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Better Option**

Please make sure that the view code that you posted is in `views/inventories/index.html.erb` file and change `Inventory.all.each` to `@inventories.each`. Then you would be able to access the search form at `http://localhost:3000/inventories`.

**Or**

From the error that you mentioned, it looks like you are doing this on `/inventories/search` page. If you want to stick to that URL, move your `index` method code into `search` method in your controller (as shown below) and add a route for `search` with GET in your routes file.

```
def search
  @q = Inventory.search(params[:q])
  @inventories = @q.result.includes(:signup)
end
```

Comment: OOOOOH yes @inventories.each is what made it work (it was in the right view).

Comment: If you were in the correct view, then I don't understand why it doesn't work without specifying the `url` in `search_form_for`. It should.

Comment: *shrug* don't know.. i was confused too, but i'm going to roll with it

Answer (score 0):

Change this;

```
def index
  @q = Inventory.search(params[:q])
  @inventories = @q.result.includes(:signup)
end
```

to

```
def index
  @q = Inventory.ransack(params[:q])
  @inventories = @q.result.includes(:signup)
end
```

Comment: Didn't work. Also according to their docs, `search == ransack` as long as search is not predefined, which it is not in my app

Answer (score 0):

I think I fell into the same situation. It might be working it's just tricky to identify. Are you getting any returns? Possible all the returns? If that is the case it might be a matter of the default search. The default search returns everything as you would expect if you had just put `Inventory.all` Try  .

`Inventory.ransack(name_eq: 'potatos').result`

this would also work

`Inventory.ransack(special_potato_eq: 'potatoes').result`

This will limit the return to exact matches of `Inventory.potato` or `Inventory.special_potato`

This is the exact bit of code that worked for me

`@q = User.ransack(email_eq: params[:q][:email])`

Checkout the reference link for other search options.

Reference: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/basic-searching